# Avoid hiding of MDI child window behind Parent's controls when the child is maximized

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make controls of MDI parent not hide the maximized MDI child when an it is maximized/resized/moved, just like ToolStrip does?

I can manually re-size/move the child window when it's not maximized so its bounds are restricted to a certain area, but when it's maximized there's nothing I [image: c]an do.

EDIT: The point is, how to make parent control (violet) act like toolstrip (orange)

Comment: Any controls on the parent normally hides the child.  Very unclear what you are talking about.  Post a minimum repro that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: Controls in the parent do not occupy the same area as the children. The question you ask is a non sequitur.

Comment: How have you placed that control there?

Comment: Put your parents controls into a panel then dock the panel to the Main MDI window.